# How can i break sentence into 2 lines only after specific word with css or (angular)javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

my code is here:

```
<p>{{comparison}}</p>

$scope.comparison = date_range
```

i want to have someting like this only when I have the second value `vs. 1988`

```
1988 vs.
2000
```

Comment: Not with CSS...JS you could

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: the problem is that i was not sufficiently clear firstly. By the way $scope.comparison = date_range that means sometimes i receive the second value with the 'vs.'  but by default i have only 1 date

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-bind-html` it can bind html code, so you can break your words with `<br />` tag.

Documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<p ng-bind-html='comparison'></p>

$scope.comparison = "1988 vs.<br /> 2000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.comparison = "1988 vs. 2000".replace(/vs\. /, 'vs.\n');
});
```

```css
.pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
<p class="pre">{{comparison}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js with RegEx solution :

```js
str="1988 vs. 2000"
var result = str.replace(new RegExp("vs.", 'gi'), function(match) {
  return  match + "\n";
});

console.log(result);
```

Output :

```
1988 vs.
2000
```

It just replaces "vs." with "vs.\n"